# if $40|a^2$ prove that $20|a$ when $a$ is an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So this is a homework question, and I'm stuck. I'm also, to be perfectly honest, not quite sure where to start.

What I tried to do is take the square root of both $40$ and $a^2$ and I got $2\sqrt{10}\text{ } | \text{ }a$  and from here I could see that if I factored 40 before I took the square root and forced the result, then I could get $(\sqrt{4} * 10) | \sqrt{a^2}$ which would give me $20|a$, but that seems, to me, to be mathematically incorrect, as I would assume that I have to take the square root of everything...I also know that I can't just assume that $a^2$ would be divisible by $2$ as that was my next thought, but $9^2 = 81$ and so dividing by 2 just because seemed like an even worse idea...

I know I haven't really tried (with any success) anything to solve this, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Notice that $40 = 2^3 \cdot 5$, so can you show that we must have $2^2 | a$ and $5 | a$?

Comment: $40|a^2$ means that $ k=a^2/40 \in Z$ .But $k$ need not be the square of an integer. So $\sqrt 40 | a $, which means that $\sqrt k=a/\sqrt  40 \in Z$ , may  be false. For example $a=100, k=250, a/\sqrt 40=5\sqrt 10\not \in  Z$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $40\mid a^2$, then $10\mid\left(\frac a2\right)^2$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: can you prove that $a$ is even? Divisible by $4$? Divisible by $5$? Do it step by step and put the pieces together.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I've solved it (I think). 

I said that $(2^3 \times 5) | a^2$ and since $a^2 = a \times a$, each prime factor of $a$ must be included in $a^2$ an even number of times. Thus we know that $a^2$ has at least $ 2^2 \times 2^2 \times 5^2$ as a factor. If I take the square root of both sides I'm left with $ (2 \times 2 \times 5) | a$ and so $20 |a$ 

Does that make sense? Or did I make a weird leap somewhere?

Comment: @Rebecca, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try a proof by contradiction.

Suppose
$20 \not\mid a$.
Then either
$4\not\mid a$
or
$5\not\mid a$.

If
$4 \not\mid a$,
then
$a 
=4k+j
$,
where
$1 \le j \le 3$.
Then $a^2
=16k^2+8kj+j^2
=8(2k^2+kj)+j^2
$.
But,
$8 \not\mid j^2$
so
$8 \not\mid a^2$,
so
$40 \not\mid a^2$.

Similarly,
if
$5 \not\mid a$,
then
$a = 5k+j$
where
$1 \le j \le 4$.
Then
$a^2
=25k^2+10kj+j^2
=5(5k^2+2kj)+j^2
$.
But $5 \not\mid j^2$,
so
$5 \not\mid a^2$,
so
$40 \not\mid a^2$.

Therefore,
if
$20 \not\mid a$,
then
$40 \not\mid a^2$,
and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

i think i have a solution.

$40=2^3\times 5|a^2=a\times a$.$\space$ therefore $2|a^2$ so $2|a$.$\space$ also, $5|a$.$\space$ so $a=(5b)(2c);\space b,c\in Z^+$.$\space$ making $a^2=5^22^2b^2c^2,$ where $2|b^2c^2$ because $2^3|a^2.$$\space$ therefore $2|b^2$ or $2|c^2$ so $2|b$ or $2|c$.$\space$ so $b^2c^2 =(2^2{p_2}^2{p_3}^2...{p_n}^2)(b^2$ or $c^2)$;$\space p_2,p_3,...,p_n$ other prime factors,$\space n\in Z^+$.

so $a^2=5^22^2(2^2{p_2}^2{p_3}^2...{p_n}^2)(b^2$ or $c^2)$; and $a=5^12^2\sqrt{{p_2}^2{p_3}^2...{p_n}^2(b^2\space or\space  c^2)}=20(\sqrt{{p_2}^2{p_3}^2...{p_n}^2(b^2\space or\space c^2)})$.  $\space \therefore 20\mid a$

Comment: What does it mean for $4\sqrt5\mid a$ when $4\sqrt5\not\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: ah i see .  my mistake

Comment: it has been edited.